# Converting Date in Where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return the sum of something within the last 30 days. My date field is a text field. My table looks something like this:

```
Client    Serial#        Hrs        MyDate
A         1              12         20200501
A         1              8          20200513
B         5              2          20200521
B         6              3          20200522
A         2              5          20200528
A         2              2          20200529
```

my Code looks like this:

```sql
SELECT Client, Serial#, SUM(Hrs)
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDate, 112) > DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())
GROUP BY Client, Serial#
```

This is the error I get
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

I tried removing the convert function and got another error:
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

So now I am stuck. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: "My date field is a text field." -- And that's where trouble starts... Use an appropriate date/time type, not a string type.

Comment: I wish my company stored their info that way too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have no other choice then to use a varchar as a date, then I would convert the one GETDATE() value to a varchar instead of converting all the rows to a date. It's possible because they are stored as YYYYMMDD. I think that would be bettter for performance (for sure if you have an index on this date column).

```
WHERE MyDate > CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(d,-30,getdate()),112)
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you! I never thought to make the today function match the character formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this using `try_convert()`:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, MyDate) > DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())
```

Your format is the SQL Server defined format for a date constant, so you don't really need the format argument.

You can find the offending values using:

```
select mydate
from t
where try_convert(date, mydate) is null and mydate is not null;
```

Note that `date`s and `datetime`s have different ranges, so just using `date` instead might fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. Says Try-Convert is not a recognized built in function. I should have specified I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: The function has an underscore, not a dash. But the version of SSMS is not relevant. What is the version of your sql server instance and what compatibility level is it using?

Comment: @Conner . . . `try_convert()` is supported in every supported version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Client, Serial, SUM(Hrs)
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDate) > DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())
GROUP BY Client, Serial
```

You don't need the format 112 for comparison

Comment: This is the error when I try this "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: See Jon Wilson's answer. That should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your convert function looks ok (although the 112 is unneeded going to datetime, that is for datetime to string conversion.)
So I bet you have some bad data somewhere in those date strings.
Dates have to be between January 1, 1753 - December 31, 9999.
Try sorting on that field and see if there is anything at the top or bottom of the list that looks suspicious.

You could add a filter:

```
    AND MyDate BETWEEN '17530101' and '99991231'
    AND LEN(MyDate) = 8
```